# Issues adding NEAR tokens in assemblyscript smart contract using u128.add() function

Tags: nearprotocol, assemblyscript, near

I have been facing issues with the use of u128.add(a, b) function. The two u128 values do not get added and I am afraid I am doing something wrong. I have checked LEARN-NEAR github page for sample projects and even changed my code to follow the patterns used, however the values don't get added.

```as
signWithFunds(amount: u128): bool {
  assert(context.sender, "Petition must be signed by an account");
  assert(this.isFunded, `not a funded petition`);
  assert(u128.ge(amount, this.minFundAmount), 
  `amount provided is less than minimum funding amount: at least ${asNEAR(this.minFundAmount)} required to sign this petition`);
  const currentTotal = this.funding;
  this.funding = u128.add(amount, currentTotal); 
  this.signature.push(context.sender);
  return true;
}
```

model.ts

[image]

main.ts

[image]

aspect test file

[image]

test result showing unexpected behaviour

[image]

Comment: Could you add some code examples to make it eadier to understand the problem?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text

Comment: @john I have edited the question to add some code

it's the signWithFunds(petitionId) function that is causing the errors.

Answer (score 1):

From the images, it looks like the test aren't receiving the expected values. The test receives `0`, but expected some other values. I don't think there's anything wrong with the `u128add` function in itself.

From the  test, you are calling a function that relies on Context's deposit, I think you need to add that to your test *(it("should sign a funded ...."), as well:

`VMContext.setAttached_deposit(someDeposit)`

Second, `signWithFunds` is relies on `this.founding` as well, which I believe is the funding in the petition itself. Maybe `petitions[0]` in your test isn't the newly created petition? We need to look at the `beforeEach` function to make sure, because otherwise, you are adding a new petition to the array, but you're referencing an older one.

Comment: thanks so much for your help John!

I discovered that the 7th line of signWithFunds should have been

``this.funding.set(u128.add(amount, currentTotal));``

Comment: That’s great. You are allowed to answer your own question. Then this question will be marked as answered.

Comment: `this.founding` I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the 7th line of signWithFunds should have been `this.funding.set(u128.add(amount, currentTotal));`

Comment: Please describe the difference this change makes.